# DFA for even concatenation of strings from a language

Tags: finite-automata, logic, haskell

If I have a [deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (DFA) with a language $W$, and I need to create another DFA that returns all the strings that are a concatenation of an even number of strings in $W$, how would I solve this?

I was considering an approach where I alternate between accepted even multiples of the DFA and unaccepted odd multiples, and essentially connect two copies of the original DFA together to create the even-DFA. However, if I have multiple accept states within the original language this would complicate things as I would need to allow connections from all of these states, and would then need to consider the presence of self-loops.

This will be implemented in Haskell, but insight either from the logic point of view or the coding point of view would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean: another DFA which *accepts* all the strings...?

Comment: Append a diagram of a toy DFA and I will post the Haskell code.

Comment: On Haskell, you might want to take a look at [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/145440/53274)

Answer (score 1):

The language you are considering is $(W^2)^*$, so you could combine standard constructions for the concatenation and the star operation.